# Automate vlookup in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm kinda stuck with this spreadsheet lookup. I've Spreadsheet A and Spreadsheet B:
Sheet A                     Sheet B

Col A         ColB          ColA   ColB

```
                        1     Damaged
                        2     Rework Needed
                        3     Customer Reject
                        4     Lost
                        5     Poor Quality
```

I need to automate this using Vlookup so that when user enters value say (1 or 2) in Col B of spreadsheet A then Col A of (Spreadsheet A) will show the values from Spreadsheet b (Damaged, Rework needed, etc)

Comment: you don't need anything  complicated for something this simple.  Use this formula in the A column (paste it in all the A cells required) and enter the values 1-5 in the B column =IF(B1=1,"Damaged",IF(B1=2,"Rework Needed",IF(B1=3,"Customer Reject",IF(B1=4,"Lost",IF(B1=5,"Poor Quality","")))))

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, It should just be a simple vlookup in column A.

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your response. I've Col A, Col B on Sheet 1 and Col A, Col B on Sheet 2. Columns on Sheet 2 have the mappings to the number as 1 Damaged, 2 Rework Needed and so on. In the Sheet 1, Col B, when the user enters the code 1, Col A (Sheet 1) should automatically populate it to Damaged. Can this be achieved? Thanks again

Comment: If you copy the vlookup formula above into Sheet1 Cell A1 it will display the text if there is a number in B1 on Sheet1. You can then drag and copy this formula down column A for each other number entered into column B on Sheet 1.